# Create batches of pandas dataframe based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, split, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
@timestamp  ISP cache_result    client_ip   client_request_host client_request_method   client_ua   client_url  client_user content_type    ... http_response_code  major   os  os_name querystring reply_length_bytes  ts_process_time ts_timestamp    type    ua_name
2018-04-17T08:12:32.000Z    cuaerH c rt,nlEIrnii.cec    TCP_REFRESH_MISS    25.204.184.124  testhost.net    GET Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Appl...   /wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/m...   -   application/javascript  ... 200 65.0    Windows 10  Windows 10  ?ver=2.2.3  25204   321 17/Apr/2018:08:12:32 -0000  testdata    Chrome
2018-04-17T08:12:32.000Z    HeE iclirueIc rat,nrncc.    TCP_REFRESH_MISS    8.157.89.174    testhost.net    GET Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Appl...   /wp-content/plugins/fusion-core/js/min/avada-p...   -   application/javascript  ... 200 65.0    Windows 10  Windows 10  ?ver=1  2825    177 17/Apr/2018:08:12:32 -0000  testdata    Chrome
2018-04-17T08:12:33.000Z    ,rrnI EnH.ceeiuclcicrat TCP_REFRESH_MISS    37.151.22.36    testhost.net    GET Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Appl...   /wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/m...   -   application/javascript  ... 200 65.0    Windows 10  Windows 10  ?ver=1  267 275 17/Apr/2018:08:12:33 -0000  testdata    Chrome
2018-04-17T08:12:34.000Z    tn.cHer uE,lecnir aircIc    TCP_REFRESH_MISS    202.165.110.43  testhost.net    GET Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Appl...   /wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/m...   -   application/javascript  ... 200 65.0    Windows 10  Windows 10  ?ver=1  341 172 17/Apr/2018:08:12:34 -0000  testdata    Chrome
2018-04-17T08:12:34.000Z    rneecHuraci ctInir cl.,E    TCP_REFRESH_MISS    174.201.44.32   testhost.net    GET Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Appl...   /wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/m...   -   application/javascript  ... 200 65.0    Windows 10  Windows 10  ?ver=1  302 180 17/Apr/2018:08:12:34 -0000  testdata    Chrome
```

Is it possible to somehow split it to 2 minutes intervals? Let's say a function that takes the whole dataframe and outputs a df with the rows of the first 2 minutes, then if called again, it outputs the df with the rows of the next 2 minutes and so on.

EDIT: A larger portion of my data is the following:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:32.000Z","ISP":"cuaerH c rt,nlEIrnii.cec","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"25.204.184.124","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.ilightbox.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"ecftdl1e","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=2.2.3","reply_length_bytes":25204,"ts_process_time":321,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:32 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:32.000Z","ISP":"HeE iclirueIc rat,nrncc.","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"8.157.89.174","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/fusion-core\/js\/min\/avada-portfolio.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"ced1tlef","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":2825,"ts_process_time":177,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:32 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:33.000Z","ISP":" ,rrnI EnH.ceeiuclcicrat","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"37.151.22.36","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/general\/fusion-waypoints.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"lde1ftce","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":267,"ts_process_time":275,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:33 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:34.000Z","ISP":"tn.cHer uE,lecnir aircIc","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"202.165.110.43","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.requestAnimationFrame.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"cl1etefd","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":341,"ts_process_time":172,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:34 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:34.000Z","ISP":"rneecHuraci ctInir cl.,E","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"174.201.44.32","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/fusion-builder\/assets\/js\/min\/general\/fusion-countdown.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"ctl1fdee","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":302,"ts_process_time":180,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:34 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:35.000Z","ISP":"ri enuaHccecrcnl,.tir EI","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"170.122.151.169","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/fusion-builder\/assets\/js\/min\/general\/fusion-flip-boxes.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"cl1feted","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":376,"ts_process_time":178,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:35 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:36.000Z","ISP":"earr ec,ulIriccnH.ci ntE","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"177.120.159.58","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.appear.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"t1lceedf","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":1331,"ts_process_time":179,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:36 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:36.000Z","ISP":"a, uEr.cnIlHeictrecrcni ","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"94.247.12.106","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/fusion-builder\/assets\/js\/min\/general\/fusion-tabs.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"fetel1dc","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":1154,"ts_process_time":86,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:36 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:37.000Z","ISP":"rlcEt.icree ncaI uHi,crn","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"149.218.159.35","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.hoverintent.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"lecte1df","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":463,"ts_process_time":172,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:37 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:38.000Z","ISP":"e,ir ctuE iccnanrceIHlr.","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"138.228.110.199","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.cycle.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"e1ftlecd","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=3.0.3","reply_length_bytes":7523,"ts_process_time":179,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:38 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:39.000Z","ISP":"nirEei,latnu.cr cIH recc","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"117.81.45.92","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.placeholder.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"cte1efdl","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=2.0.7","reply_length_bytes":874,"ts_process_time":178,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:39 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:39.000Z","ISP":"Eic,e rlHccacrnuntI .rie","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"62.189.164.148","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/general\/fusion-tooltip.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"fe1eltdc","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":452,"ts_process_time":89,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:39 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:40.000Z","ISP":"It.crue,lare rHiic cncnE","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"136.44.153.177","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/includes\/lib\/assets\/min\/js\/general\/fusion-ie1011.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"1dcetlef","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=1","reply_length_bytes":526,"ts_process_time":89,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:40 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:41.000Z","ISP":"nIr,erecluiiHac cr.Ec nt","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"228.104.233.205","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/bootstrap.scrollspy.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"ec1edltf","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=3.3.2","reply_length_bytes":1060,"ts_process_time":172,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:41 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:42.000Z","ISP":"lrne,tEcuc eircIHc.air n","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"168.41.158.162","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/assets\/min\/js\/library\/jquery.sticky-kit.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"d1efctle","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=5.4.2","reply_length_bytes":1208,"ts_process_time":185,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:42 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:27.000Z","ISP":".cccti a neuleEc,rriHnrI","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"113.202.240.119","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/revslider\/public\/assets\/js\/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"d1eflcet","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=5.4.7","reply_length_bytes":38335,"ts_process_time":313,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:27 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:28.000Z","ISP":"lnniueeiIH.ca rtrc ,ccEr","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"190.220.94.243","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/10\/viettan.png","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/png","device":"Other","dnet":"delcfet1","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":1549,"ts_process_time":170,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:28 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:29.000Z","ISP":"ein.rcaelc uEn tIHcrcr,i","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"31.13.51.177","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/03\/facebookviettan.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"edteclf1","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":6705,"ts_process_time":178,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:29 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:31.000Z","ISP":"clr,Hncie uaIciEncr. ter","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"128.129.21.211","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/03\/chantroimoimedia.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"edce1tlf","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":6216,"ts_process_time":90,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:31 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:43.000Z","ISP":"tnrI.ccenruiirlE He,c ca","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_MISS","client_ip":"225.14.12.26","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/themes\/Avada\/assets\/min\/js\/general\/avada-contact-form-7.js","client_user":"-","content_type":"application\/javascript","device":"Other","dnet":"ec1tfled","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":"?ver=5.4.2","reply_length_bytes":504,"ts_process_time":178,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:43 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:43.000Z","ISP":"tariirs oftpooorCoMcn","cache_result":"ERR_CLIENT_ABORT","client_ip":"173.38.196.130","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit\/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/7.0 Mobile\/11A465 Safari\/9537.53 BingPreview\/1.0b","client_url":"\/amp_preconnect_polyfill_404_or_other_error_expected._Do_not_worry_about_it","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"Spider","dnet":"1ceetlfd","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":404,"major":1.0,"os":"iOS","os_name":"iOS","querystring":"?1523952720000","reply_length_bytes":43261,"ts_process_time":1075,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:43 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"BingPreview"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:44.000Z","ISP":"i.nae,crHntc uiEcrlr ecI","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"217.198.69.197","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/dong-tam-bat-giu-cong-an-640x360.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"1teedfcl","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":38627,"ts_process_time":228,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:44 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:45.000Z","ISP":"c rcEn.,er reHciulitcanI","cache_result":"TCP_MISS","client_ip":"204.99.48.109","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/TMDuc.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"ceteldf1","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":206,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":141770,"ts_process_time":512,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:45 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:47.000Z","ISP":"Ht, eri enaErurcIcc.ciln","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"20.204.32.235","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/03\/f1-13.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"tecfe1dl","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":161573,"ts_process_time":593,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:47 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:47.000Z","ISP":"Ei .ne,cHncrterarilccu I","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"224.60.44.234","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/f1-9-177x142.jpg","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/jpeg","device":"Other","dnet":"1fecldet","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":10410,"ts_process_time":170,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:47 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:12:48.000Z","ISP":"irre,n Iec.rciu ntlcHacE","cache_result":"TCP_REFRESH_HIT","client_ip":"68.18.239.120","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/65.0.3325.181 Safari\/537.36","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","client_user":"-","content_type":"image\/gif","device":"Other","dnet":"fcledet1","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":65.0,"os":"Windows 10","os_name":"Windows 10","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":847,"ts_process_time":89,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:12:48 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Chrome"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:21:23.000Z","ISP":"nnH rGmelbeen iOHzt","cache_result":"TCP_MISS","client_ip":"234.197.117.162","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit\/534.58.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/5.1.8 Safari\/534.58.2","client_url":"\/Nhin-Thay-Gi-Tu-Mot-Hoi-Nghi.html","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"Other","dnet":"1ecfeldt","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":301,"major":5.0,"os":"Mac OS X","os_name":"Mac OS X","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":0,"ts_process_time":523,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:21:23 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Safari"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:22:03.000Z","ISP":"Tx  osoy1bcy dPdx hreah ia nOo ra-et51XsiaPttt","cache_result":"ERR_CLIENT_ABORT","client_ip":"218.202.132.77","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; A1601 Build\/LMY47I; wv) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/4.0 Chrome\/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari\/537.36 [FB_IAB\/FB4A;FBAV\/166.0.0.66.95;]","client_url":"\/bat-binh-voi-toa-an-len-lut-giao-hat-van-hanh-noi-lua-hiep-thong-voi-tu-nhan-luong-tam\/","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"A1601","dnet":"ftee1dlc","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":301,"major":166.0,"os":"Android","os_name":"Android","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":17707,"ts_process_time":31255,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:22:03 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Facebook"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:21:25.000Z","ISP":"ne z briltHmOnHGeen","cache_result":"TCP_MISS","client_ip":"69.10.61.78","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit\/534.58.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/5.1.8 Safari\/534.58.2","client_url":"\/nhin-thay-gi-tu-mot-hoi-nghi\/","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"Other","dnet":"cfdt1lee","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":5.0,"os":"Mac OS X","os_name":"Mac OS X","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":19351,"ts_process_time":1302,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:21:25 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Safari"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:21:29.000Z","ISP":"gooLLeG lC","cache_result":"TCP_HIT","client_ip":"167.182.156.107","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)","client_url":"\/-","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"Other","dnet":"cee1tfld","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":null,"os":"Other","os_name":"Other","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":16962,"ts_process_time":0,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:21:29 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Other"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:21:28.000Z","ISP":"eLLol GCgo","cache_result":"TCP_HIT","client_ip":"207.89.148.171","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)","client_url":"\/-","client_user":"-","content_type":"text\/html","device":"Other","dnet":"c1dleeft","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":200,"major":null,"os":"Other","os_name":"Other","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":16962,"ts_process_time":0,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:21:28 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Other"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:28:51.000Z","ISP":"oeClL LgoG","cache_result":"TCP_IMS_HIT","client_ip":"98.217.204.182","client_request_host":"testhost.net","client_request_method":"GET","client_ua":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build\/MMB29P) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari\/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot\/2.1; +http:\/\/www.google.com\/bot.html)","client_url":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/accelerated-mobile-pages\/templates\/design-manager\/design-3\/fonts\/ptserif\/PT_Serif-Web-Regular.ttf","client_user":"-","content_type":"-","device":"Spider","dnet":"efd1etlc","host":"testhost.deflect.ca","http_request_scheme":"http","http_request_version":"HTTP\/1.1","http_response_code":304,"major":2.0,"os":"Android","os_name":"Android","querystring":null,"reply_length_bytes":0,"ts_process_time":0,"ts_timestamp":"17\/Apr\/2018:08:28:51 -0000","type":"testdata","ua_name":"Googlebot"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2018-04-17T08:12:32.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:11:33.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:14:31.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:25:35.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:16:36.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:10:42.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:18:38.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:09:29.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:30:40.000Z",
            "2018-04-17T08:21:21.000Z",
        ],
        "value": [9, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 1, 2, 0, 3],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it by defining a [generator function](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/):

```py
def chunk(df, delta_in_min):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        df: dataframe to split in chunks.
        delta_in_min: size of chunk in minute (at least one).


    Yields:
        Chunk of input dataframe of the given size.
    """
    start = df.index[0]
    while True:
        if delta_in_min <= 0:
            yield df
            break
        end = start + pd.Timedelta(value=delta_in_min, unit="m")
        if end > df.index[-1]:
            yield df.loc[(df.index >= start), :]
            break
        yield df.loc[(df.index >= start) & (df.index < end), :]
        start = end
        if start > df.index[-1]:
            break
```

And then:

```py
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.set_index("timestamp").sort_index()
```

From here, you can call `print(next(chunk(df, 2)))` repeatedly to get each chunk or use a for loop, like this:

```py
for s in chunk(df, 2):
    print(s)

# Output
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:09:29+00:00      2
2018-04-17 08:10:42+00:00      8
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:11:33+00:00      2
2018-04-17 08:12:32+00:00      9
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:14:31+00:00      3
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:16:36+00:00      7
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:18:38+00:00      1
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:21:21+00:00      3
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value]
Index: []
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:25:35+00:00      4
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value]
Index: []
                           value
timestamp
2018-04-17 08:30:40+00:00      0
```

Comment: The line `yield df.loc[start:end, :]` leads to `KeyError: Timestamp('2018-04-17 08:14:32+0000', tz='UTC')`. Any idea of what causes the error?

Comment: As far as I can understand is that you used a simpler case where there exists data for each minute, but in my case there might not be an index corresponding to exactly two minutes after the first index, so I need to choose the one that is closer to 2 minutes. Please check my edit in my post to see a larger part of my data.

Comment: Right, I've updated my answer to take that into account. The helper function now works with the additional data you provided. Cheers.